# Convert URLs to another in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How I can convert URL to another use PHP
exemple

```
domain.com to domain2.com
```

and

```
domain.com/content to cdn.domain2.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Convert "domain.com" to "domain2.com"**

```
<?php 
$re = '/(?=\.)/m';
$str = 'domain.com
';
$subst = '2'; //add text

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo "The result of the substitution is ".$result;
?>
```

**1. Result:**

```
domain2.com
```

**2. Convert "domain.com/content" to "cdn.domain2.com"**

**REGEXP:**
**1.**

```
/(?=\.)/m
```

**2.**

```
/\/.*/m
```

**3.**

```
/^(?=\w)/m
```

**2. Code PHP:**

```
<?php 
$re = '/(?=\.)/m';
$str = 'domain.com/content';
$subst = '2';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str); //domain2.com/content

$re = '/\/.*/m';
$str = $result; //domain2.com
$subst = '';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

$re = '/^(?=\w)/m';
$str = 'domain2.com';
$subst = 'cdn.';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str); //cdn.domain2.com

echo $result;
?>
```

**Result:**

```
cdn.domain2.com
```

**Enjoy**

Comment: The only regex that may require an `/m` modifier is `'/^(?=\w)/m'`.